# Safari: SVG in <label> elements don't seem to work with "click" events

Tags: javascript, svg, mobile-safari

I've got a site design with SVG elements for "fancy" radio buttons and checkboxes. The basic idea is that the actual HTML element is effectively hidden (moved off the visible page, because IE doesn't like input elements to be actually hidden) and then nice-looking SVG icons are used for the visible interactive elements.

The problem is that Safari on iOS seems to not propagate "click" events on the SVG elements up to the `<label>` wrappers. So I've got:

```
<input type=checkbox class=not-visible id=foo>
```

then

```
<label for=foo><svg>...</svg></label>
```

On all desktop browsers and Android, that works fine. Tapping the SVG icon propagates a "click" event to the `<label>`, which results in a "click" on the actual checkbox element. On Safari, it does not work. I've tried setting via CSS the `pointer-events` property to `none`, and that *sometimes* helps but not always. I have not been able to figure out what the pattern is.

Ideas?

*edit* — it occurs to me that I left out two facts of interest:

- When there's text in the `<label>` along with the SVG, "click" events are correctly synthesized on mobile Safari for taps on the text, but taps on the SVG itself don't;
- I'm using the [Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library, which has generally not caused me problems but there's no reason not to suspect that it *might* have something to do with the behavior.

Comment: It may seem a stupid idea, but it doesn't hurt to try: what happens if you set the CSS `{cursor: pointer;}` for that SVG? (without the `{pointer-events: none;}`, of course)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado not a bad idea but I already do that (for the `<label>` as a whole), and the cursor does correctly render as a pointer. Note that when the `<label>` also include text, then Safari does correctly create "click" events.

Comment: Do that for the SVG. I read some time ago that the click only bubbles up in iOS if the SVG has a cursor style set (don't ask me why...).

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Fastclick and making sure that my `<svg>` elements are styled with

```
pointer-events: none;
```

seems to make things work. I'm not 100% sure it *always* works, but in my test cases I can't find any of my fancy checkboxes or radio buttons that don't work.